# "Flatly denied that he had copied" vs. "flatly denied the charges that he had copied"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, nouns

> The student flatly denied that he had copied in the examination hall.

That sentence is not correct, I found that it must be "flatly denied the charges that".

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean _"The student flatly denied that he had copied in the examination hall."_ against _"The student flatly denied **the charges** that he had copied in the examination hall."_?

Comment: I would vote to close this just for spelling "grammar" incorrectly on ELU.

Answer (score 4):

***Both*** complementation patterns are correct and commonly used:

> Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary
>
> **de•ny**
>
> v.t. ...
>   1. to state that (something declared) is not true: *to deny an accusation*.

[In this example the direct object of *deny* is a term on the same level as the general 'declaration' / statement / accusation / charges.]

> Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged
>
> **deny**
>
> vb ... (tr)
>   1. to declare (an assertion, statement, etc.) to be untrue: *he denied that he had killed her*

[In this example the that-clause complementing *deny* spells out the actual declaration / statement / charge.]

Comment: +1. I guess this pretty much answers the question. I would have given a similar answer.